# Can't import certificate to cacerts

Tags: ssl, cas

I have a web app that I get redirected to from my CAS server. But I got this exception:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

So I googled a bit and found a lot of threads about it. I found out that my self created certificate must be inside javas `cacerts`. So I figured out how to add it:

```
keytool -import -alias tomcat -file tomcat.crt -keystore {path to cacerts}\cacerts
```

However, I get the following error messages (german/english):

German:

```
Keytool-Fehler: java.lang.Exception: Public Keys in Antwort und Keystore stimmen nicht überein
```

English (translation):

```
Keytool-Error: java.lang.Exception: Public Keys in the answer and keystore does not match
```

How can I make the public keys match?

Answer (score 0):

```
keytool -import -alias tomcat -file tomcat.crt -keystore {path to cacerts}\cacerts
```

You left out the `-trustcacerts` argument.